# Linq to Entities Selecting Data with Max Date?

Tags: c#, linq

I am having issue selecting maxDate within also selecting other columns within a query

This is the query that I am trying to convert to linq to entities. The tableexpression would return a list of ids along with the corresponding max insertdates

```
    WITH TableExpression
AS
(
SELECT   Id, Max(InsertDate) as MaxInsertDate
FROM     MyTable
WHERE    UploadDate BETWEEN '10/1/2018' AND '12/12/2018'
GROUP BY Id
)

SELECT  * 
FROM    MyTable t Join TableExpression on t.Id = TableExpression.Id
WHERE   t.InsertDate = TableExpression.MaxInsertDate    
        AND UploadDate BETWEEN '10/1/2018' and '12/12/2018'
```

EDIT UPDATE: Thanks to the answer below this query gets me what I need if I do a .ToList(); However I need to include this query as a join

```
  var maxDateQuery = ctx.MyEntity
        .Where(m => m.InsertDate >= fromDate && m.InsertDate <= toDate)
        .ToArray()
        .GroupBy(x => x.Id)
        .Select(g => new { Id = g.Key, MaxInsertDate = g.Max(y => y.InsertDate) }).AsQueryable();
```

The second issue is the join clause

```
var mainQuery = ctx.MyTable
        .Where(m => m.InsertDate >= fromDate && m.InsertDate <= toDate).AsQueryable();



 var joinedQuery = maxDateQuery.Join(mainQuery, max => max.Id, main => main.Id, (mdq, mq) => new { maxRecords = mdq, mainRecords = mq })
                                                  .Select(joined => new
                                                  {
                                                      main = joined.mainRecords,
                                                      max = joined.maxRecords
                                                  }).ToList();
```

I am getting a crazy error once I hit the join statement:  ***"This method supports the LINQ to Entities infrastructure and is not intended to be used directly from your code."***

Comment: Your max is only returning the date and doesn't contains the other properties in the object.. You previous posting is better.  Why do you need a range of dates and a max?

Comment: The first SQL query needs to be converted to Linq

Comment: No, it doesn't. Use raw SQL or group the results that you are getting back from the database. This is both easier and faster than trying to produce some SQL based on a LINQ statement.

Comment: The posting was edited after my comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could group the in-memory results after you have selected the records from the database, e.g.:

```
var maxDateQuery = ctx.MyTables
        .Where(m => m.InsertDate >= fromDate && m.InsertDate <= toDate)
        .ToArray()
        .GroupBy(x => x.Id)
        .Select(g => new { Id = g.Key, MaxInsertDate = g.Max(y => y.InsertDate)) }};
```

This should give you an `IEnumerable<a'>` where `a'` is an anonymous type with an `Id` and a `MaxInsertDate` property if that's what you want.

Trying to convert fairly complex SQL queries to LINQ-To-Entities is pointless. You should either group the in-memory results like above or use raw SQL queries

Comment: I think your solution is the appropriate one. Since you group by Id. and then select 
 the values.

Comment: This works however I need to include it in a join. Ive updated the original question

Comment: Why? Trying to convert fairly complex SQL statements to LINQ-To-Entities makes no sense. Either group the in-memory results as I suggested or use raw SQL queries.

Comment: Our standards wont allow raw queries is the issue. It would be easy for me to use the first raw query but they want EVERTHING converted to Linq to Entities

Comment: Good luck then. "They" should probably do some learning :) Linq-To-Entities is not a replacement for SQL. But if you don't want to write raw SQL, you don't have to as you may group the results using C# code.